# What is the MAAS node login?

Tags: maas

I have a problem, when I want to login in nodes. My nodes are created via MAAS dashboard, where I'm adding nodes. But when installation completes I'm asking to login and password to get into the node. But they wasn't shown or I missing something. I need to login to nodes to check clock and solve other issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're trying to log in through SSH.  Did you also register your SSH key(s) with MAAS?  You need to do that, before you allocate the node to yourself (in the UI that's the Start Node button).

I believe the default username is `ubuntu` — so if you've gone through these steps, you should be able to ssh into the node with username ubuntu and no password.

Comment: Yes you are right I understood it before I read your post. But the main problem I had never register ssh keys. I know it's simple task but I'm fresh with Linux. So if you give me more information about how to do that. If I would install nodes manually I think it would be easier to do.

Comment: I'm noting that I had to use the following syntax:  "ssh ubuntu@nodename.dnszonename".  I then had to enter the passphrase to use my /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa file's private key.  (I had earlier added the SSH key in the MAAS console.)

Answer (score 1):

OK what I got is that you had successfully installed maas, successfully added the nodes and they are at **Ready** state.

Hence all you have to do is export your ssh key on maas controller `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048`, press enter couple of times, open the key `vi ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and copy the whole thing.

Then log in the maas gui, click on your **username** on the top right corner => **preferences** => **add ssh key** and past it.

Now go to all the nodes, **start** them, and boot them up *if they didn't automatically*.

Finally `ssh node_IP_address` from the maas controller.

Comment: After you install OpenStack on your MAAS setup JuJu will issue a variety of static and dynamic IP addresses.  There are times when you think you know what the IP address of a node is and it's something else.  So be careful using just the IP address, in other words.  You might think that you're testing a "nova-compute" service node and you're accidentally on the one that's running something more critical.