# Is there a way to set the MAAS password via a preseed?

Tags: password, juju, maas

As has been asked before ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173112/maas-node-login) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181507/what-username-password-does-maas-assign-to-nodes)) I need to set a password during commissioning for my nodes. I realize that ssh keys are set (and I have one) but I need to log in to the node directly as networking is not coming up properly.

Is there a way to change this in the preseed?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [MAAS documentation](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/configure.html#altering-the-preseed-file), altering the preseed files is not recommended, because it might prevent MAAS from properly commissioning and installing nodes.

Are you able to connect to the node using SSH and user `ubuntu`? If so, looking in `/var/log/dmesg` and `/var/log/syslog` can help diagnosing startup and networking issues.

If you need to alter the preseeds, you can find the full documentation, describing all supported settings [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/preseed-contents.html). There is a section about changing the default root user account and password (see "Account setup"). If you change these though, MAAS might have trouble bringing the node up to Ready state.