# MAAS - Access to node

Tags: networking, server, juju, maas, openstack

MAAS Region controller (`regionA.maas`) is running up, synched with one Rack Controller (`rackA.maas`), who has actually one node (`nodeA02.maas`) with address: 192.168.1.38:2225.

Had a first automatic `commissioning` on friday evening (*wasn't in office when happend*) with `nodeA02.maas`. Meanwhile this node went back to `commissioning failed`, and I've no more access to `nodeA02.maas`.

Tried to restart one right after the other:
- first `regionA.maas` (region controller)
- second `rackA.maas` (rack controller)
- third `nodeA02.maas`

`nodeA02.maas`is booting under MAAS -> Great!!, this is what I tried to do.
But terminal shows up login credential created my MAAS as the most well know screen:

```
    Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS ubuntu tty1

    Ubuntu Login: _
```

**MY QUESTION NOW:**
How may I access to `nodeA02.maas`, if I haven't log in credentials?

**TO SPECIFY**
All SSH keys (public keys) where added to MAAS before this actually situation.

I searched/googled around, but wasn't successful in finding some useful stuff. Maybe someone with experience in this?

My actually most closes reads are these:
[What is the MAAS node login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173112/what-is-the-maas-node-login)
[What username/password does MAAS assign to nodes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181507/what-username-password-does-maas-assign-to-nodes)
[MAAS boots inaccessible nodes when there's no SSH registered for a given user](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/986185)
[problem with authentication via SSH on MaaS Nodes](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2229640)

Any of these provides useful stuff that worked for me.

Comment: Do you have internet on your pxe network? you can check the machine logs in /var/log/maas/syslog/.....

Comment: @Junaid, thanks for your answer. Indeed, there is internet... but I encountered some more lecture and as well, the system requirement to run machine commissioning nodes, needs anyway fro IPMI and PXE, as well for a BMC, which obiviously nor regionA nor rackA as well as noceA01/A02 has (due are desktop computers / Mac Pro environment). So external setup is needed. In exception you want to run KVM, so you ca configure them with `virsh`.

Comment: Are you able to commission nodes now? Feel free to ask any questions and attach the logs so that community can help you in debugging. You can use maas mailing list for quick response to your queries.

Comment: @Junaid Thank you so much... Indeed I still have issues in commissioning nodes. I'm going to use KVM thru `virsh`, so to be able to manage nodes virtually. I'm pretty shure you can help out this issue. :D